# It is possible to write in octave directly in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, package, octave, nuget-package

I would like to know if there is a way to directly program in octave - or other open source similar to matlab - within a VB.net project (maybe there are some packages).
In this way I could use the calculation functions of octave (which are more advanced than those within vb.net) and write interface and publish an executable with vb.net.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used it, but maybe [Octave.NET](https://github.com/triforcely/Octave.NET) would be of interest to you. They say "This library is an attempt to bridge Octave and .NET worlds in a user-friendly and cross-platform manner while keeping single code-base and clean interface."

Comment: yes but it seems to only support c#?

Comment: You will find a lot of things only have instructions for C#, but it is mostly the same for VB.NET. Just remember to declare variables in the VB.NET fashion, and arrays use round brackets in VB.NET whereas they use square brackets in C#, e.g., `someArray(idx)` vs `someArray[idx]` respectively. A little investigation will give you answers to other differences.