# Run Octave function form shell

Tags: function, shell, octave

It is possible to write a function directly in the octave shell?

```
A=147;
B=26.3;
C=5.4;
d=0.35*A;

function S=function_test(A,B,C,d)
                                                
S=2*A*B*C*d;

end
```

I tried this but if I wanted to know the value of "S", this error appears:

```
error: 'S' undefined near line 1, column 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It is possible to write in octave directly in VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326460/it-is-possible-to-write-in-octave-directly-in-vb-net)

Comment: it looks like that was also your question.  Perhaps it would be best to combine/clarify the question over there to include this specific difficulty. it may help someone provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You does it correctly. But you missed indicating how you call the function. For me, no error occurs:

```
≫ function_test(1,2,3,4)
ans = 48
≫ res = function_test(1,2,3,4)
res = 48
≫ S = function_test(-1,3,5,7)
S = -210
≫
```